# Remove extra column level from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

My dataframe looks like this.

[image]

It's the result of this code:

```
survival_by_position = survival_by_position.groupby("POSITION")["SURVIVED"].value_counts().rename("Count").reset_index()
survival_by_position = survival_by_position.pivot(index = "POSITION", columns = "SURVIVED", values = "Count")
survival_by_position = survival_by_position.rename(columns = {False: "DEAD", True: "SURVIVORS"})
```

I want it to look like this.

[image]

That is, **POSITION** should remain the index, but the columns **DEAD** and **SURVIVORS** should "come down", and **SURVIVED** should disappear. I've tried to (re)set the index, create a new dataframe and assign it the right index and columns, nothing worked. I either get all NaNs, or the default integer index, or some error. I know this has got to be some multi-index trickery, but I am not familiar with that so I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to rename the column axis:

```
survival_by_position = survival_by_position.rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Full code:

```
survival_by_position = (
    survival_by_position.value_counts(['POSITION', 'SURVIVED'])
                        .unstack('SURVIVED').fillna(0).astype(int)
                        .rename(columns={True: 'DEAD', False: 'SURVIVORS'})
                        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Some modifications:

1. replace `groupby` / `value_counts` by `value_counts`
2. replace `pivot` by `unstack`
3. remove `rename('Count')`
4. remove `reset_index()`

Comment: Renaming the column axis doesn't "move" down the two column names. I know the result is still functionally identical to a normal dataframe (or so it seems to me), but I wonder why there doesn't seem to be a way to make it look like one. 

I didn't know about the `unstack` trick, very cool way to avoid `groupby`.

Comment: If you want your expected output, you have to append `.reset_index()` (modification 4)

Comment: That works, but then "POSITION" is no longer the index. Is there way to make it such, at that point?

Comment: No this is the default representation of a dataframe in jupyter notebook. The index is one row below. You can't change this.

Comment: That's right, I remember now.